# Can I call a yield return method outside of a loop?

Tags: c#, yield-return

There are situations in which a method should be used with yield return, but not in others.

The question is that if a method with yield return is used to assign values ​​to a variable only one item is returned.

In this situation two methods will be needed, one for regular use and the other with yield return.

Is there some way to use the method with yield return outside a loop?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question, but I dont see any case where `yield return` is essential. There's always another solution.

Comment: Perhaps you can add some possible code/usage describing what you want (even if it doesn't quite compile for obvious reasons)

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: I can't make heads nor tails of this question.

Comment: I'm elaborating a example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean can you *use* `yield return` outside of a loop?

The answer is yes:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetStrings()
{
    yield return "foo";
    yield return "bar";
    yield return "baz";
}
```

...but this would be an unusual use case of `yield return`.

Comment: Not necessarily. I've used that pattern several times for simple configuration properties/methods where the members of then collection are known beforehand.

Comment: Unusual but not unheard of.  I've used it in cases where the method returning the `IEnumerable` is polymorphic and some concretions return a fixed set of items.  You can also use it in addition to a loop (to append or prepend fixed items).

Comment: I use yield return when doing mvc custom model validation all the time.  Each yield is in an if statement checking if a condition is valid, and returns an error to add to the error collection

Comment: I think this specific usage is unusual, because you can just as well write `return new[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };`.

Comment: @svick the code mentioned simplifies the real logic. As Andrey has comment many times you would like to have result aggregation, in which the results are conditioned/calculated, and you won't be able to use return new[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" }; so this pattern is quite convenience.

Answer (score 0):

A method that uses `yield return` will return an `IEnumerable` and possibly something more specific like an `IEnumerable<int>`.  If you are only interested in the first item, you can call:

```
int myInt = myYieldReturnMethod().First();
```